Make Beamer header "behave" similar to a book header
I am preparing math notes for online lessons in Beamer. How can I make the header "behave" in a way similar to a header of a book.
In the MWE below, when I have one section only, the output is the first image. When I add a section or a subsection I get the output in the second image. (I suppose that is what people want or like in a classic presentation.) But I cannot afford losing any vertical space for displaying what the previous section/subsection was or what the next section/subsection will be. When I get to a new section or subsection, I just want the one-line section or subsection in the header replaced with the new one. How can I do that?
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{split}
\section{Calculus}
\subsection{Function}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Definition}
Function definition.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Limit}
\begin{frame}{}
There is no limit.
\end{frame}
\end{document}




You could redefine the headline template. Here an example that only shows the current section and subsection:
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{split}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  {\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \centering
    \insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
    \centering
    \insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{Calculus}
\subsection{Function}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Definition}
Function definition.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Limit}
\begin{frame}
There is no limit.
\end{frame}
\end{document}

